# Mysql Query not returning values if timestamp is not there

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here I have a query which returning aggregate of values based on 5 minutes intervals of time stamp.
Here is the query

```
SELECT  
       DATE_FORMAT(`recived_on`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + 
             INTERVAL (MINUTE(`recived_on`) - MINUTE(`recived_on`) MOD 5) MINUTE AS receivedOn,SUM(quantity) AS Quantity
 FROM tablename WHERE DATE(`recived_on`) = '20210129'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`recived_on`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + 
             INTERVAL (MINUTE(`recived_on`) - MINUTE(`recived_on`) MOD 5) MINUTE;
```

This query is returning values like below.

```
2021-01-29 00:05:00 1
2021-01-29 00:15:00 1
2021-01-29 00:45:00 1
2021-01-29 01:05:00 1
2021-01-29 03:00:00 1
2021-01-29 04:45:00 1
2021-01-29 06:15:00 2
2021-01-29 06:40:00 1
```

For example between 00:05:00 and  00:15:00 there were no records . So it was not showing anything. But I need timestamp data like data for every 5 mins even it is zero . For example if there were no records then it should return 0  like below

```
2021-01-29 00:05:00 1
2021-01-29 00:10:00 0
2021-01-29 00:15:00 1
2021-01-29 00:20:00 0
2021-01-29 00:25:00 0
2021-01-29 00:30:00 0
2021-01-29 00:35:00 0
2021-01-29 00:40:00 0
2021-01-29 00:45:00 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and to see your approach is correct: Why do you need the query to return zero when there are no records?

Comment: @KIKO Software, If i export data as csv then Client is going to generate graph in excel. So based on client requirement

Comment: In Excel you can [use a date or time axis](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/display-or-change-dates-on-a-category-axis-d5a8146b-d457-43d1-8602-c1d23c96d650) which would be the most correct way to graph this data anyway. OK, but if you want to show the zero values, that won't work. How do you export the data?

Comment: @KIKO Software, yeah I already suggested that . But he wants to see in which time intervals data is not there. So I need to have those interavls even if there is no data.

Comment: OK. One, thing that would simplify your query is that you can `GROUP BY Quantity`. Not really helpful, but a simpler query is always nice.

Comment: Could be and solved in PHP (it was tagged initially) by using the `DatePeriod` class and cross-referencing with the query results while looping the period. That's one approach, if you don't insist that the problem should be solved inside the query.

Comment: @ KIKO Software I tried with group by quantity. It is also returning the same results

Comment: Yes, I know, it's the same result, but the query is a lot shorter that way. I would probably also use PHP to add the zero values. Do you use PHP to export to CSV?

Comment: @KIKO Software, yes but in this first shot he was asking with in mysql query.

Comment: Left join your query to a tally table of intervals

Comment: The standard method for this is to generate a temporary table, containing all the time slots, and then JOIN that with your current results. See [method 1 here](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/mysql-sequential-generate-series-numbers-time.html).